# Lightbox for images and youtube videos which works on the IPAD

Tags: ipad, youtube, lightbox

I've looked everywhere for a lightbox which works for both images and youtube videos on the IPAD and I can't find one. Am I missing one?

Comment: Yes. http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation/

Comment: doesn't work on the IPAD

Comment: :-/ runs choppy in IE and the add this is bit clunky... any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fancybox did the trick. It "lightboxes" youtube videos through an iFrame, which is key because youtube is able to sort out that your browser belongs to an iPad/iPhone and then converts the media to a non-flash format.

[Fancybox in action on my soccer toy's website](http://www.kikbo.com)